# Не хотят подключаться sqlite и mysqli на денвер

Tags: sqlite, php

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь подключить **sqlite** и **mysqli** на денвер, но как только вставляю dll файлы в папку ext и раскомменирую **extension=php_sqlite.dll** и **extension=php_mysqli.dll**, при перезапуске денвера тут же вылезает подряд 2 ошибки ,такого вида
[image]

Что это может быть? ато уже зла не хватает. Знаю что они и так должны идти с denver'ом (даже стандартным), но не работает. Как только устанавливаю расширенный пакет денвера, вылазят опять же эти ошибки. OS - Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как же это раздражает когда идет одна проблема за другой...

В общем у кого такая же непонятка возникает:

Сносим денвер.
Качаем [денвер](http://www.denwer.ru/), не верим тому что туда стандартно входит sqlite!

Качаем [дополнительный модуль PHP5](http://www.denwer.ru/packages/php5.html), устанавливаем

Далее.. если вам не везёт также как и мне, и при запуске денвера постоянно вылетает ошибка что не найден файл **msvcr71.dll**, качаем его [здесь](http://www.dll.ru/dll/22749.html) и запихиваем в папке с php (мой путь на денвере: **C:\WebServers\usr\local\php5\сюда**)

И вот теперь запускаем, лично мне это помогло.